# Typo3 HMENU Configuration literals

Tags: typo3

I am new in Typo3 and I have this definition of my HMENU in my first page:
(class /typo3/fileadmin/layouts/ts/main.ts)

```
# 3-Stufige Hauptnavigation
tmp.navi_main = HMENU
tmp.navi_main {
    1.expAll = 1
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="no no0 first">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="no no0">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="no no0 last">|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
            ATagTitle.field = title // abstract // description
            stdWrap.dataWrap = <span>|<span class="nav-subtitle">{field:subtitle}</span></span>
            ATagParams = class="a0"
            allStdWrap.insertData = 1 
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1 
        }
        ACT < .NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act act0 first">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act act0">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act act0 last">|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
            ATagParams = class="act0 a0"
        }
        CUR < .NO
        CUR = 1
        CUR {
             wrapItemAndSub = <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act cur act0 first">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act cur act0">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act cur act0 last">|</li>
             wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
             ATagParams = class="act0 cur a0"
        }
        wrap = <ul id="navi-main" class="navi-main0"> | </ul>
        noBlur = 1
    }
    2 < .1
    2 {
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="no no1 first">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="no no1">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="no no1 last">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="a1"
        }
        ACT < .NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act act1 first">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act act1">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act act1 last">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="act1 a1"
        }
        CUR < .NO
        CUR = 1
        CUR {
             wrapItemAndSub = <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act cur act1 first">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act cur act1">|</li> |*| <li id="nav{field:uid}" class="act cur act1 last">|</li>
             wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
             ATagParams = class="act0 cur a0"
        }
        wrap ( 
                <ul class="navi-main1"> 
                    | 
                </ul>
             )
    }
    #excludeUidList = 11,12,13
}
```

In my main page I have this image[image] I need to add new item in my hMenu (blue div with an hyper link a href), but I dont know where to add the new Literal? 
Can somebody can help me about this? The literals are in database? or where?
Thanks!

Comment: Add a new page and TMENU generate menu with this additional entry.

Comment: why do you have `1.NO.allStdWrap.insertData = 1`? why is `2.CUR.ATagParams = class="act0 cur a0"`? why do you add special classes to the a tag (you can catch these tags with pure CSS selection `li.act > a`)? what do you mean with 'Literal'? you might add another picture with the elements you want to add.

Comment: After reviewing the original website: the icons are added as a CSS pseudo element, using markup like `<i class="icon-book"></i>`. So you'll have to extend your stylesheet. As you can see for yourself, your TypoScript doesn't contain this markup, this _could_ be part of the `title` field in your database.